# Rehosted RuleSetEditor with VB Intellisense

Tags: vb.net, workflow-foundation-4, rule-engine

I rehosted the RuleSetEditor in my application. Is there a way to make it understand VB expressions, instead of C# expressions? In the following picture, you can see, that the Condition, and the "Then Actions" and "Else Actions" use the "this" keyword, which is C#. Would it be possible to use the VB keyword "Me", or even better, no prefix at all?

[image: Rule Set Editor]